# Symfony login retorna Invalid credentials

Tags: login, symfony3, symfony

Estoy desarrollando un login con Symfony 3.4. Cuando intento ingresar con dicho login me genera el error **Invalid credentials.**. Seguí e implementé el login siguiendo la siguiente enlace [tutorial](https://jaromero.es/symfony-sistema-usuarios/).
En mi base de datos tengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuya estructura sql es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Implementé mi clase usuario:

```
/**
  * Usuario
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="usuario")
   * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ComensalesBundle\Repository   \UsuarioRepository")
 */
   class Usuario implements UserInterface 
  {
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nombreUsuario", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $nombreUsuario;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="contrasenia", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $contrasenia;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="rolUsuario", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $rolUsuario;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set nombreUsuario
 *
 * @param string $nombreUsuario
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setNombreUsuario($nombreUsuario)
{
    $this->nombreUsuario = $nombreUsuario;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nombreUsuario
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNombreUsuario()
{
    return $this->nombreUsuario;
}

/**
 * Set contrasenia
 *
 * @param string $contrasenia
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setContrasenia($contrasenia)
{
    $this->contrasenia = $contrasenia;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get contrasenia
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getContrasenia()
{
    return $this->contrasenia;
}

/**
 * Set rolUsuario
 *
 * @param string $rolUsuario
 *
 * @return Usuario
 */
public function setRolUsuario($rolUsuario)
{
    $this->rolUsuario = $rolUsuario;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get rolUsuario
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRolUsuario()
{
    return $this->rolUsuario;
}

public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->nombreUsuario;
}

public function getSalt()
{
    return null;
}

public function getRoles()
{
  // En este caso definimos un rol fijo, en el caso de que tengamos un campo role en la tabla de la BBDD    tendríamos que hacer $this->getRole()
    return array('ROLE_USER');
}

public function eraseCredentials()
{
}

public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->contrasenia;
}

 // NO PERSISTIDO EN LA BD

private $plainPassword;

public function getPlainPassword()
{
    return $this->plainPassword;
}

public function setPlainPassword($plainPassword)
{
    $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;
}
}
```

Por otro lado, configuré mi **service.yml**

```
    providers:
    user_provider:
        entity:
            class: ComensalesBundle:Usuario
            property: nombreUsuario

encoders:
    ComensalesBundle\Entity\Usuario:
        algorithm: bcrypt


firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /login
access_control:
    - { path: ^/registro, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

El controller que me muestra el formulario

```
 namespace ComensalesBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

     class DefaultController extends Controller
     {
      /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        // Recupera el servicio de autenticación
        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        // Recupera, si existe, el último error al intentar hacer login
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // Recupera el último nombre de usuario introducido
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        // Renderiza la plantilla, enviándole, si existen, el último error y nombre de usuario
        return $this->render('login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
    }

    /*
    * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
    */
    public function logoutAction(Request $request)
    {
       // UNREACHABLE CODE
    }
}
```

El template no tiene muchos secretos:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}

{# Muestra el error en caso de existir#}
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">

    {# Input para el campo email #}
    <label for="username">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

    {# Input para el campo contraseña #}
    <label for="password">Contraseña:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

    {# Ruta a la que redirige si hay éxito #}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{path('ventas_panel')}}" value="/" />

    <button type="submit">Entrar</button>
</form>

{# Enlace al registro #}
  {#    <p><a href="{{ path('register') }}">Registro</a></p>#} 
  {% endblock %}
```

Cuando intento ingresar, con el usuario y pass registrado en la base de datos, me genera un error de credenciales. Se me ocurre que el error puede ser un problema de conversión o de tipos de datos. Si me pueden orientar se los agradecería.

Edit: les copio una parte del log:
**security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException(code: 0): Bad credentials.**
Tal vez sea relevante a la hora de ayudarme. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de trabajar con esto, me di cuenta de que no estaba cifrando las contraseña con el algoritmo **bcypt** como habia especificado en **security.yml**.

Eso lo puede observar, al ver el siguiente tutorial [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onT0DpobhXQ) donde en varios pasos muestra las configuraciones de los archivos.

Si deseas crear los usuarios directmente en la base de datos, la contraseña debe estar cifradas, por eso recomienda usar la siguiente app: [calculadora bcypt](https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator)

Con guardar la contraseña cifrada, se resolvio el problema. Ahora queda seguir trabajando con el proyecto. A veces la falta de experiencia nos juega una mala pasada.
Saludos